# VBA-SQL return to matching row

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I use the following code to match a range of article numbers and return each corresponding article numbers price.

While the returning prices are correct it does not print the price on the correct row. Each price gets printed two  cells below where it should be printed.

RowNo = the article number I wanna match, and these resides in the E column.

What am I missing? :)

```
 SQLStr = "SELECT convert(money, poCOST) FROM [dbo].[Database]" & _
"WHERE [RowNo] IN( '" & Join(Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("E40:E500").Value), "','") & "')"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

Set rs = .Execute(SQLStr)
End With

p = 40

While Not rs.EOF
    For v = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
        ActiveSheet.Cells(p, v + 10).Value = rs.Fields(v - 1).Value
    Next v
    p = p + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

cn.Close
```

Comment: I made a workaround by using match index to another table.